# No Line found? reading file error?

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop

I get a `No Line found` error for this reading while loop.
Even when I print everything with `input.nextLine()` it says countt == 0. 
Which means, while loop is not even working?

```
public class ReaderFile {
    public static Scanner input;
```

Try-Catch of the input.

```
try{
            input = new Scanner(new File(fileLocation)).useDelimiter(",");
        }
        catch (IOException ioException)
        {
            System.out.print("PROBLEM");
        }
```

This is the code I'm having problems with.

```
int countt = 0;
        input.nextLine();
        while(input.hasNext())
               {
                      System.out.print("TEAMSTart\n");
                      int ID = input.nextInt();
                      String teamName = input.next();
                      String coachFirst = input.next();
                      String coachLast = input.next();
                      String mentorFirst = input.next();
                      String mentorLast = input.next();
                      String teamFs = input.next();
                      String teamSS = input.next();
                      input.nextLine();
                      Team team = new Team (teamName, ID, coachFirst, coachLast,mentorFirst,mentorLast,teamFs,teamSS);
                      store.add(team);
                      System.out.print(ID);
                      countt = countt+1;
                      //System.out.print("\n"+countt);
                }
```

This is the text file that I'm reading

```
TeamNumber,Team Name,Coach First,Coach Last,Mentor First,Mentor Last,Team Fin Sponsor,Schools or Sponsoring Organization,TmMem1First,TmMem1Last,TmMem2First,TmMem2Last,TmMem3First,TmMem3Last,TmMem4First,TmMem4Last,TmMem5First,TmMem5Last,TmMem6First,TmMem6Last,TmMem7First,TmMem7Last,TmMem8First,TmMem8Last
6842,Reagan Ray-Guns,Judy,Mallon,Aziz,Valdez,Texas Workforce Commission,REAGAN H S,Steven,Cepeda,Alan,Yue,Tim,Callaway,Damon,Bertucci,Samuel,de Olvieira,Samuel,Day,,,,
6888,Islanders,Judy,Maldonado,Brady,Trevino,Three Rivers Robotics,THREE RIVERS MIDDLE,Shireen,Cowdrey,Dee,Roundtree,Steven,Callaway,Francisco,Bermea,,,,,,,,
7004,GREENHILL Tops,Kanat,LaBass,Harvey,Pflueger,GREENHILL Boosters,GREENHILL SCHOOL,Harvey,Pflueger,Sandra,Day,Denny,Rodriguez,shirley,Couvillon,Carly,Szarka,,,,,,
```

Comment: post the code where `input` is initialized

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you use a [`try-with-resources` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and **please** do not just say **PROBLEM** when you get an `Exception`.

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileLocation))) {

} catch (IOException ioException) {
    ioException.printStackTrace();
}
```

I would read by line. Remember you should call `hasNext` before you attempt to read and then you can split on `,` like

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    int col = 0;
    String line = input.nextLine();
    String[] arr = line.split(",");
    System.out.print("TEAMSTart\n");
    int ID = Integer.parseInt(arr[col++]);
    String teamName = arr[col++];
    String coachFirst = arr[col++];
    String coachLast = arr[col++];
    String mentorFirst = arr[col++];
    String mentorLast = arr[col++];
    String teamFs = arr[col++];
    String teamSS = arr[col];
    store.add(new Team(teamName, ID, coachFirst, coachLast,
            mentorFirst, mentorLast, teamFs, teamSS));
    System.out.println(ID);
}
```

It appears that your file starts with a header ... you can add a

```
if (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String hdr = input.nextLine();
}
```

before the above while loop to skip it.

Comment: well i get `NullPointerException` . which means a reference error?

Comment: Where do you get the `NullPointerException`? The stacktrace should give you a line number.

Comment: `NullPointerException` was at 84 line. but now all the input lines for input ,input2 , input3 , input4 and input5.

Comment: @ann The above has no `input2` or `input3` or `input4` ... where is line 84? I want to help you, but you need to give me enough information to help you.

Comment: Line 84 is input.nextLine(); 
even after i included the if statement you stated, still same error.
now gives me `cannot find Symbol` error for the inputs. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Put the `if` before the `while` loop, but both go in the `try`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reader {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = null;
        try {
            input = new Scanner(new File("C:/Mohan_Backup/DDR/input.txt"))
                    .useDelimiter(",");
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            System.out.print("PROBLEM");
        }

        int countt = 0;
        System.out.println(input.nextLine());
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print("\nTEAMSTart: ");
            int ID = input.nextInt();
            String teamName = input.next();
            String coachFirst = input.next();
            String coachLast = input.next();
            String mentorFirst = input.next();
            String mentorLast = input.next();
            String teamFs = input.next();
            String teamSS = input.next();
            input.nextLine();
            // Team team = new Team (teamName, ID, coachFirst,
            // coachLast,mentorFirst,mentorLast,teamFs,teamSS);
            // store.add(team);
            System.out.print(ID);
            countt = countt + 1;
            // System.out.print("\n"+countt);
        }
    }

}

This code works  and shows the below output
TeamNumber,Team Name,Coach First,Coach Last,Mentor First,Mentor Last,Team Fin Sponsor,Schools or Sponsoring Organization,TmMem1First,TmMem1Last,TmMem2First,TmMem2Last,TmMem3First,TmMem3Last,TmMem4First,TmMem4Last,TmMem5First,TmMem5Last,TmMem6First,TmMem6Last,TmMem7First,TmMem7Last,TmMem8First,TmMem8Last

TEAMSTart: 6842
TEAMSTart: 6888
TEAMSTart: 7004
```

I have commented the line 35,36,37 because i don't have source for the same.

Comment: , gives me a `NullPointerException` .   @MohanRaj

Comment: Paste the Null pointer exception stacktrace. Above is my code and output for the same. Please check the file contents. My filelocation is different